# Python Webdriver Unable to locate the xpath in facebook for Liked and shared button in pages

Tags: python

i am writing a code on python by using selenium that login into Facebook and Like a Facebook page i requested. it works to login but after opening the Facebook page i requested, it wont like the page it shows error saying 'Attribute-error[image]: 'list' object has no attribute 'click''. maybe it didn't get the correct xpath ,any ideas?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! could you please paste your code and not an image so others would be able to reproduce this. providing a full exception would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use chropath extension in chrome

Answer (score 1):

See line 27 of your code: you are using `find_elementS` instead of `find_element`.

`find_elements` always returns a list of elements, so when you are trying to do `like.click()`, it fails. Try using `find_element_by_xpath` at the line 27 of your code, it should work.

Good luck!